# Web.config max uploadsize

Tags: wcf, web-config

I am getting ready to publish a WCF to the web however I have a small problem, for some reason the webconfig ignores my endpoint configuration. I am trying to set it up so it can take files up to 50 mb in byte[] however the only thing that passes trough is files less then 100 kb. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my webconfig?

Here is the config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*;AccountKey=*" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="500000000" /> </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding"  scheme="https"  bindingConfiguration="basichttp"  />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basichttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" messageEncoding="Text">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="peaEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*.database.windows.net;initial catalog=pea;persist security info=True;user id=*;password=*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the client's **app.config** also configured as such?

Comment: The client app is UWP, the service is connected to the client vie service reference and hosted at azure. By default it downloads its config from the reference have common configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way of doing this but I found a solution to my problem on my own. The mistake here is that I don't have endpoint defined and name to the contract

```
<services>
  <service name="PeaWCF.PeaEntryEntities">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:56662/PeaEntryEntities.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="NewBinding1" listenUri="/"  contract="PeaWCF.IPeaEntryEntities" name="DefaultEndpoint" />
  </service>
</services>
```

hope this can help someone else that is trying set up endpoints and size limit to WCF and client.